# object hbase is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop

Tags: scala, hadoop, sbt, hbase

I am trying to use `HBase` API in my Scala project, but I'm getting an error when I try:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase
```

The error is "object hbase is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop"

I am using sbt 1.3.12 to build my project, this is a part of the `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.7.3",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.3",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.2.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.2.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-protocol" % "1.2.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.2.1"
)
```

Do you know how to solve the issue?

Comment: Jad, did you make it to work?

Comment: Checked the configuration above and worked fine. Did you restart sbt after you added the `libraryDependencies`? Where do you `import`? Is this `sbt console` perhaps? Worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the `val hbaseVersion =`  that is in the middle of your `build.sbt`. Try to remove it:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.7.3",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.3",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.2.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.2.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-protocol" % "1.2.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.2.1"
)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Cj6Q5pbxQjGq8ARCngnGsg).